# Problem having a route in different modes . LARAVEL

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In this route:

```php
Route::post('/doctor/{doctor}/service/bulk', 'ServiceController@bulkCreate');
```

I will send this request:

```json
[
 {
   "service_id": 1,
   "time_taken": "01:30:00"
 }
]
```

And there is no problem in localhost and this response will be returned:

```json
{
    "success": true
}
```

but in production state, I will receive this response:

```json
{
    "success": false,
    "error": {
        "code": 0,
        "message": "The request is invalid.",
        "trace": [
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/ValidatesWhenResolvedTrait.php",
                "line": 26,
                "function": "failedValidation",
                "class": "App\\Http\\Requests\\BaseRequest",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Providers/FormRequestServiceProvider.php",
                "line": 30,
                "function": "validateResolved",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\FormRequest",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php",
                "line": 1084,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Providers\\FormRequestServiceProvider",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php",
                "line": 1048,
                "function": "fireCallbackArray",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Container\\Container",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php",
                "line": 1033,
                "function": "fireAfterResolvingCallbacks",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Container\\Container",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php",
                "line": 687,
                "function": "fireResolvingCallbacks",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Container\\Container",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php",
                "line": 615,
                "function": "resolve",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Container\\Container",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php",
                "line": 767,
                "function": "make",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Container\\Container",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php",
                "line": 79,
                "function": "make",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php",
                "line": 46,
                "function": "transformDependency",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteDependencyResolverTrait.php",
                "line": 27,
                "function": "resolveMethodDependencies",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php",
                "line": 41,
                "function": "resolveClassMethodDependencies",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
                "line": 219,
                "function": "dispatch",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
                "line": 176,
                "function": "runController",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
                "line": 680,
                "function": "run",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 30,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/app/Http/Middleware/ApiRole.php",
                "line": 30,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 163,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "App\\Http\\Middleware\\ApiRole",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 53,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php",
                "line": 41,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 163,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 53,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php",
                "line": 43,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 163,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 53,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php",
                "line": 58,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 163,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\ThrottleRequests",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 53,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 104,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
                "line": 682,
                "function": "then",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
                "line": 657,
                "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
                "line": 623,
                "function": "runRoute",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
                "line": 612,
                "function": "dispatchToRoute",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
                "line": 176,
                "function": "dispatch",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 30,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
                "line": 57,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 163,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 53,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
                "line": 21,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 163,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 53,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
                "line": 21,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 163,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 53,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
                "line": 27,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 163,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 53,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
                "line": 62,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 163,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 53,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
                "line": 104,
                "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
                "line": 151,
                "function": "then",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
                "line": 116,
                "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
                "type": "->"
            },
            {
                "file": "/var/www/html/public/index.php",
                "line": 55,
                "function": "handle",
                "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
                "type": "->"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And here are my codes:
bulkCreate:

```php
  /**
     * @param DoctorServiceBulkCreateRequest $request
     * @param Doctor $doctor
     * @return JsonResponse
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
     */
    public function bulkCreate(DoctorServiceBulkCreateRequest $request, Doctor $doctor)
    {
        $this->authorize('bulkCreate', [ServiceDoctor::class, $doctor]);
        $doctor->serviceDoctors()->createMany($request->all());
        return $this->sendSuccess();
    }
```

DoctorServiceBulkCreateRequest, rules:

```php
   public function rules()
    {
        return [
            '*.service_id' => 'required|integer|unique:service_doctor,service_id',
            '*.time_taken' => 'required|date_format:H:i:s'
        ];
    }
```

I am very confused and I do not know where the problem comes from.
Nobody knows what the problem is?

Comment: might indicate that the service id provided already exists on your production database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change unique to exist and solve it